# insert the POST list to the db in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

We encountered a problem. Can you help?
I am sending a list via POST. lists will be recorded in the table in two fields. Send List in HTML.
As follows, validate result from html.

Your list data are:

1. ('csrfmiddlewaretoken', ['..'])
2. ('x1', ['1', 'Закройный'])
3. ('x2', ['2', 'Закройный'])
4. ('x3', ['3', 'Закройный'])

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Testmodel(models.Model):
    ws1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ws2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

input.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
            {% for work_stations in ws %}
                {% if work_stations.is_active %}
          <input name="x{{ work_stations.id }}" value="{{ work_stations.id }}">
          <input name="x{{ work_stations.id }}" value="{{ work_stations.category }}">
          {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Testmodel


def createpost(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_data = (list(request.POST.lists()))

#Here I need to save list_data to the database. The following code does not work.
        mylist = list_data

        Testmodel.objects.bulk_create([Testmodel(**{
            'ws1' : x[0],
            'ws2' : x[1]})
            for x in mylist])
```